# hide attribute (title) on mouseover div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a learning game, it is a simple memory game.

The game was designed to run on phones and tablets, variables were used in the attribute (title), when used in computers, when mouse over, look at the (title) the name of the little card, without fail.

is possible change the attribute (title) for (alt)? or hide title onmouseover?

thank you very much for your help

CODE:

```
        function game(){
            var _PLACES=new Array(0,1,2,3,4,5);
            shuffle(_PLACES);

            var _RIG=new Array();
            var _LEF=new Array();
            for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
                _RIG[i]='<div onclick="select_card(1,this);" class="card" title="card_'+i+'"><i><b>'+_GAME["hanzi"][i]+'</b>'+_GAME["definition"][i]+'</i></div>';
                _LEF[i]='<div onclick="select_card(2,this);" class="card" title="card_'+i+'"><i>'+_GAME["pinyin"][i][_GAME["correct"][i]]+'</i></div>';
            }

            shuffle(_RIG);
            shuffle(_LEF);

            $("#OPTIONS").html('<div id="rig">'+_RIG[0]+_RIG[1]+_RIG[2]+_RIG[3]+_RIG[4]+_RIG[5]+'</div><div id="lef">'+_LEF[0]+_LEF[1]+_LEF[2]+_LEF[3]+_LEF[4]+_LEF[5]+'</div>');
        }

        function shuffle(o){
            for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
            return o;
        };

        var _card=new Array(0,7,7);
        function select_card(side,card){

            if(_card[side]==7){
                card.style.background="#FFFFFF";
                var el=card.getElementsByTagName("*");
                for(var i=0;i<el.length;i++){
                    el[i].style.visibility="visible";
                }

                _card[side]=card.title.toString().replace("card_","");
            }else{
                $("#"+(side==1?"rig":"lef")+" .card[name!='res']").attr("style","");
                $("#"+(side==1?"rig":"lef")+" .card[name!='res'] *").attr("style","");
                _card[side]=7;
                select_card(side,card);
                return;
            }

            if(_card[1]!=7 && _card[2]!=7){
                if(_card[1]==_card[2]){
                    _AU.src=_GAME["audio"][_card[2]];
                    try{_AU.play();}catch(err){}
                    $('.card[title="card_'+_card[1]+'"]').attr("name","res"+_card[1]);
                    $('.card[title="card_'+_card[1]+'"]').attr("onclick","");
                    _GAME["points"]++;
                    $("#score").html("points: "+_GAME["points"]+"/6");
                }else{
                    $('#rig .card[title="card_'+_card[1]+'"]').css("background","#FDD");
                    $('#lef .card[title="card_'+_card[2]+'"]').css("background","#FDD");
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $(".card").each(function(ind){
                            try{
                                if(this.name.toString().search("res")=="-1"){
                                    $(this).attr("style","");
                                    $(this).find("*").attr("style","");
                                }
                            }catch(err){
                                $(this).attr("style","");
                                $(this).find("*").attr("style","");
                            }
                        });
                    },1000);
                }
                _card[1]=7;
                _card[2]=7;
            }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078388/hiding-title-tags-on-hover

Answer (score 0):

Storing variable in the `title` attribute is not the best idea, since that is specifically used for titling things.  Instead you should use `data-*` attributes.  Since you are using jQuery, it already has support for easy reading/writing of the data attributes anyway: http://api.jquery.com/data/

you can have `<div class="card" data-card-num="2"></div>` and then use `$(".card").data("card-num");` to read the value, which will return `2` in this case.

You can also write & change data by passing the value as a 2nd parameter:

Set: `$(".card").data("card-num", 99);`

Get: `$(".card").data("card-num");` --> `2`

---

You can even set/get complex objects and other arbitrary data.

Set: `$(".card").data("cardObj", {card: 2, isSelected:false});`

Get: `$(".card").data("cardObj").isSelected` --> `false`

Get: `$(".card").data("cardObj")` --> `{card: 2, isSelected:false}`