# Preventing the tooltip from appearing when hovering over images?

Tags: html, css, class, hover, tooltip

I would like to remove the popup tooltip when hovering over certain images (not all) on my site. Is there a way to accomplish this through CSS? If not, what's the easiest way?

I have images in the typical format:

```
<img src="source.jpg" class="noTooltip" alt="My Alt" title="My Title" />
```

I can't remove the alt or title from the tag because they're needed in other places.

Thanks!
Brendan

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078388/hiding-title-tags-on-hover

Comment: Just make the title blank for the ones you don't want the tooltip to show for.  title = " "

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

`.noTooltip {pointer-events:none;}`
or
`.noTooltip img {pointer-events:none;}`