# Recreating the default tool tip in browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

On Windows, Chrome

The Aim 1:-

Hover over an element to show the tool tip, freeze it and inspect it using Chrome Development Tools to get the default styles.

What I have tried?

Tried the solutions here

[Inspect hovered element in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370838/inspect-hovered-element-in-chrome)

[How to inspect JQuery UI tooltip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815749/how-to-inspect-jquery-ui-tooltip/58207769#58207769)

The Problem:-

all listed solution do not work.

1 - Pressing F8 causes the tool tip to disappear. (while in the source tab)

2 - Using "Event Listener Breakpoints", ""mouseout" method does nothing.

3 - Using the "debugger" or "console method" does not work as nothing happens.

The Aim 2:-

Recreate the the too tip with custom styles.

What I have tried?

Tried the solution here.

[How to change the style of the title attribute inside an anchor tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-the-title-attribute-inside-an-anchor-tag)

The Problem:-

1 - Both the default tool tip as well as the custom tool tip are shown. (need only to show the custom tool tip)

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip[title]:hover::after {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  left: 25px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span title="I am Tool Tip" class="tooltip">Hover over me</span>
```

Comment: _"(need only to show the custom tool tip)"_ - then _don't_ use the name of the attribute that causes the default tooltip, but name it something else.

Comment: @CBroe. Like Brahma Dev has done below? Using aria-label!

Answer (score 3):

You should `aria-label`. This way you cover both accesibility and your custom tooltip.

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip:hover::after {
  content: attr(aria-label);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  left: 25px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span aria-label="I am Tool Tip" class="tooltip">Hover over me</span>
```

Comment: This will have SEO implications since we are removing the titl attribute

Comment: In that case you'll have to use javascript to remove the title when hovering.

Comment: Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078388/hiding-title-tags-on-hover

Comment: @Jawad according to my interpretation of the documentation, this would not be a problem. I think the aria-label would replace the title. I quote from the documentation: """If you give your <iframe>s a title (...) aria-label is not necessary. But, if present, the aria-label will take precedence over the title (...)""" I might be wrong because the documentation only adresses accessibility, not SEO, but I think search engines take the accesibility information into account also. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-label

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to remove the `title` attribute, then have it in a child element with `pointer-events: none;`. Although I don't see the point of doing it, as you say, for SEO implications...

```css
.tooltip:has([title]) {
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip [title] {
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.tooltip:hover [title]:after {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 25px;
  color: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.tooltip:active {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="tooltip">
  <span title="I am Tool Tip">Hover over me</span>
</a>
```

Comment: In case it's set on the anchor tag, <a href="#">...</a>, pointer-events: none; will cause the href not to work

Answer (score 0):

As, in fact, your `span` is not an empty element (you say to Imhvost that it contains an anchor), you can explicitly set an empty title to the anchor with javascript, it will hide the title of the parent `span`. (you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78183361/4698373))

So, in your case :

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".tooltip[title]  > a");

for (element of elements) {
    element.title = "";
}
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip[title]:hover::after {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  left: 25px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span title="I am Tool Tip" class="tooltip"><a href="#">Hover over me, I'm a link!</a></span>
```