# Hide original title box on hover

Tags: html, css

I have made a custom title box and the old one still displays along with the new one when I hover over my icons.
I have provided an
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJ4Q4.png) of what is happening. If you look at the image you can see a black box with "Homepage" and white text above the icon. I want the white text only.

```css
header {
  background-color: #195190;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.nav-buttons {
  display: flex;
  gap: 30px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  animation: slideInL 1s ease-in-out;
}

.nav-button {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-button:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

li[title]:hover::after {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  background-color: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200"
  />
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <ul class="nav-buttons">
      <li title="Homepage">
        <a id="navhomepage" href="./index.html" class="nav-button">
          <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
            home
          </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li title="Photopage">
        <a id="navphotopage" href="./Photosite/index.html" class="nav-button">
          <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
            photo_camera
          </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li title="Startside">
        <a id="navstartside" href="./Startside/index.html" class="nav-button">
          <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
            web
          </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li title="Contact">
        <a id="navcontact" href="#Contact" class="nav-button">
          <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
            contact_page
          </span>
```

I tried disabling the title using js but that ended up disabling both of them.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I can't reproduce the stated problem "old title box still displays along with the new one". Also, I suggest changing the text color to black to make the title box visible here.

Comment: Update the snippet in your question please. Don't link to a third party site

Comment: @SyndRain It is reproducible in Firefox for me at least. OP probably should just use the `data-*` attribute instead of `title` or at least use some JS to disable the default behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test thist

```
li[title]:hover::after {
                  content: "";
                  position: absolute;
                  width: 120px;
                  bottom: 100%;
                  left: 50%;
                  margin-left: -60px;
                  background-color: #195190;
                  color: #fff;
                  text-align: center;
                  padding: 5px 0;
                  z-index: 1; 
    }
                
    li[title]:hover::after {
    }
```

Edited:

Html:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <ul class="nav-buttons">
      <li>
        <a id="navhomepage" href="./index.html" class="nav-button">
          <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
            home
          </span>
          <span class="nav-text">Homepage</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a id="navphotopage" href="./Photosite/index.html" class="nav-button">
          <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
            photo_camera
          </span>
          <span class="nav-text">Photopage</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a id="navstartside" href="./Startside/index.html" class="nav-button">
          <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
            web
          </span>
          <span class="nav-text">Startside</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a id="navcontact" href="#Contact" class="nav-button">
          <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
            contact_page
          </span>
          <span class="nav-text">Contact</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </header>
</body>
```

Css

```
header {
  background-color: #195190;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.nav-buttons {
  display: flex;
  gap: 30px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  animation: slideInL 1s ease-in-out;
}

.nav-button {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-text {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  background-color: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  white-space: nowrap; 
}

.nav-button:hover .nav-text {
  display: block;
}

.nav-button:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: This removed both titles.

Comment: Oh f*** sry i just read the text you want only the white one which getting showed over the icon right?

Comment: Yeah, When I try to hide the default one I end up hiding both.

Comment: He adding that black box under the mouse because the title in the <li>

Comment: @Ant I edited it should work now

Answer (score 1):

You can "patch" your page with javascript, setting a blank `title` to the `a` link inside the `li`.

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-buttons li[title] > a");

for (element of elements) {
    console.log("discarding title of", element.id);
    element.title = "";
}
```

```css
header {
    background-color: #195190;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.nav-buttons {
    display: flex;
    gap: 30px;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    animation: slideInL 1s ease-in-out;
}

.nav-button {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-button:hover {
    color: #ccc;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

li[title]:hover::after {
    content: attr(title);
    position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
    background-color: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <ul class="nav-buttons">
            <li title="Homepage">
                <a id="navhomepage" href="./index.html" class="nav-button">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                        home
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li title="Photopage">
                <a id="navphotopage" href="./Photosite/index.html" class="nav-button">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                        photo_camera
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li title="Startside">
                <a id="navstartside" href="./Startside/index.html" class="nav-button">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                        web
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li title="Contact">
                <a id="navcontact" href="#Contact" class="nav-button">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                        contact_page
                    </span>
```